# Similar to ptr_map container

Tags: c++, qt, boost, stl

I decided to throw out boost from my project. Any way to have best implement of container instead of `ptr_map`? As I know it holds a smart pointer as a value. Maybe `QMap<Key, std::shared_ptr<Type*>>` could do that?

Comment: Yuck, Qt containers... why not copy the necessary Boost headers over with maybe a bit of editing?

Comment: @larsmans I just use Qt lib in my project.

Comment: That choice is yours to make, but I'd recommend against the Qt containers. I've had to work with them in the past, which has not a pleasant experience. After I left, the project lead decided to scrap Qt for everything except the GUI in favor of Boost.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you choose to stop using Boost?

Comment: @larsmans boost slows project build time. Maybe, if I wouldn't use some exotic classes I will not see big difference at all...

Comment: @JohnDibling The speed of project building event at my Core I7 2.2

Comment: Boost's ptr_containers don't actually hold shared pointers. Under the hood they are std containers of `void*` with all the machinery to ensure that you access the values correctly and to manage the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with `std::map<Key, std::shared_ptr<Type>>`? Advantages over `QMap`:

- standard solution
- has better worst-case time bounds (`QMap` is a skip list, so expected time bounds are the same)
- 64-bit clean whenever the compiler/library is (`QMap` uses `int` for sizes)
- interface is more similar to `boost::ptr_map`